# Using intrisinc function size for automatic arrays in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is: CodeBlocks  16.01

This is my code:

```
Program Array_To_Procedure

Implicit  none

Integer, dimension (10) :: My_Array

Interface

  Subroutine Fill_Array (a)

    Integer :: i
    Integer, intent ( inout ) :: a (*)

  End subroutine Fill_Array

  Subroutine Print_Array (a)

    Integer :: i
    Integer , intent ( in ) :: a (*)

  End subroutine Print_Array

End interface

  Call Fill_Array ( My_Array )
  Call Print_Array ( My_Array )

End program Array_To_Procedure

Subroutine Fill_Array ( a )

Implicit none

    Integer :: i
    Integer, intent ( inout ) :: a (*)

    Do i = 1 , size( a )

       a(i) = i + 1

    End Do

Return
End subroutine Fill_Array

Subroutine Print_Array ( a )

Implicit none

    Integer :: i
    Integer , intent ( in ) :: a (*)

    Do i = 1 , size( a )

       Write(*,*) a(i)

    End Do

Return
End subroutine Print_Array
```

My intention is to use intrinsinc function `size` for size determination of automatic array in subroutines. In my case, afther the compile process I got this message:

`The upper bound in the last dimension must appear in the reference to the assumed size array 'a'`  |

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Maybe the duplicate is not the best one should I re-open? But the issue is the same and very simple, you are using an assumed size array `(*)`. You cannot use `size` on these. You can use that only for explicit suze `(n)` or assumed shape `(:)` arrays. Automatic arrays is something completely different, not an argument ar all.

Comment: And learn modules and ditch the interface bloks, they are error-prone.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no way for determination upper bound of `array (*)` whitout passing a explicit size from subroutine argument list?

Comment: Exactly, there is no way.